# urllib.urlopen cannot find reference

Tags: python

Now I can get the code to execute but when i call the function and pass the parameter it tells me invalid syntax. I tried with '10.1.1.27' and "10.1.1.27" as well as the below code but I can't get it to work. Any advice is appreciated.

```
download_permitted(10.1.1.27)
```

Below is the function in it's entirety

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
def download_permitted(address):
    f=urlopen("http://"+address+"/config?action=get&paramid=eParamID_MediaState")
    response = f.read()
    if (response.find('"value":"1"') > -1):
        return True
    f = urlopen("http://" + address + "/config?action=set&paramid=eParamID_MediaState&value=1")
```

Comment: have you tried looking at the documentation? Which IDE are you using?

Comment: `urllib.urlopen()` is python2, and is not available in python3. In python3, you can use  `urllib2.urlopen()`

Comment: I am using Pycharm. Even if I try urllib2.urlopen() it doesn't work. Gives me the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is no such method as `urllib.urlopen()`. Instead, try the following.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def download_permitted(address):
    f = urlopen("http://" + address + "/config?action=get&paramid=eParamID_MediaState")
    ...
```

Comment: I tried that and I still get the same error. I'm using Pycharm by the way

Comment: That works now. However I modified my original post with the updated information. Thanks for this by the way.